# Formatting networkx data for Keras sequential model

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, networkx

I am trying to build a classifier for graphs based on the minimum colors needed to color them. I am using the networkx library to produce the graphs and evaluate the minimum number of colors needed to properly color them. Here is the data generation:

```
nodes=10
numGraphs=1000
probability= .25
graphs=np.empty(numGraphs, dtype=dict)
colorings=np.empty(numGraphs, dtype=dict)
numColors=np.zeros(numGraphs)

#Producing array of random graphs 
for i in range(numGraphs):
    graphs[i]=nx.erdos_renyi_graph(nodes,p)


#Coloring the array of graphs
for i in range(numGraphs):
    colorings[i]=nx.coloring.greedy_color(graphs[i], strategy="largest_first")



#Storing the minimum colors needed for each graph and the largest color needed from all graphs
#The numColors is the desired output of the network for each graph.
for i in range(len(colorings)):
    numColors[i]=max(colorings[i].values())+1
    
maxColor=max(numColors)

#Converting graphs from dicts to flattened arrays which are nodes^2 long, This is the input data
for i in range(numGraphs):
    graphs[i]=nx.to_numpy_array(graphs[i])
    graphs[i]=graphs[i].flatten()
```

Splitting data and model:

```
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split (graphs, numColors, test_size = 0.2)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(nodes, input_shape=(800,), activation='relu', name="input"))
model.add(Dense(100,activation='sigmoid',name="layer2"))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', name="layer3"))
model.add(Dense(int(maxColor), activation='softmax', name="ouput"))
model.summary()
```

```
Model: "sequential_17"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input (Dense)                (None, 10)                8010      
_________________________________________________________________
layer2 (Dense)               (None, 100)               1100      
_________________________________________________________________
layer3 (Dense)               (None, 100)               10100     
_________________________________________________________________
ouput (Dense)                (None, 10)                1010      
=================================================================
Total params: 20,220
Trainable params: 20,220
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

The model should take in an array of arrays which are nodes^2 long and classify it into one of "maxColor" number of classes. In this case, maxColor=10 and x_train is a array of 800 arrays populated with 100 0's and 1's. I figured then that the input shape should be that of x_train, hence input_shape(800,0). However when I try to compile and fit the model:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train,y_train, epochs=200, batch_size=15)
```

I get the following error:
"ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_input to have shape (800,) but got array with shape (1,)"

I also tried reshaping x_train:   x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (1, x_train.shape[0]))

But got an error for the target value: "ValueError: Error when checking target: expected ouput to have shape (10,) but got array with shape (1,)"

Answer (score 0):

you are making a mistake about dimension. if your input is 800 array of 100s 0 and 1 the you input dimension should be 800,100 . you should make your model input shape equal to 100 as here `model.add(Dense(nodes, input_shape=(100), activation='relu', name="input"))`

also dont reshape this `x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (1, x_train.shape[0]))`
you need to reshape like this `x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (-1, x_train.shape[1]))`

make sure last dimension is 100, as in model now.